# How to extract all IMDb ID's from string

Tags: regex

I have a block of text where I want to search for IMDb link, if found I want to extract the IMDdID.

Here is an example string:

```
http://www.imdb.com/Title/tt2618986
http://www.google.com/tt2618986
https://www.imdb.com/Title/tt2618986
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1979376/?ref_=nv_sr_1?ref_=nv_sr_1
```

I want to only extract `2618986` from lines 1, 3 and 4.

Here is the regex line I am currently using but am not having luck:

```
(?:http|https)://(?:.*\.|.*)imdb.com/(?:t|T)itle(?:\?|/)(..\d+)(.+)?
```

https://regex101.com/r/ERtoRz/1

Comment: Did you try it with the global flag? https://regex101.com/r/ERtoRz/2

Comment: Ah I knew it was something really small. Can you create an answer for this please? Thanks

Comment: You could omit the multiline flag as well. No need for an answer, there was only a flag not activated :) But I think you might simplify your patttern to `^https?://www\.imdb\.com/[Tt]itle[?/]([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` See https://regex101.com/r/aECBPN/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in only extracting the ID, so `2618986`, none of the comments quite nail it, since they match `tt2618986`. Building on top of @The fourth bird answer, you will need to separate `tt2618986` into two parts - `tt` and `2618986`. So instead of a single `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`, have `[a-zA-Z]+([0-9]+)`.

```
^https?://www\.imdb\.com/[Tt]itle[?/][a-zA-Z]+([0-9]+)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aECBPN/3)

You can then extract the `2618986` part by calling group 1.

Answer (score 1):

This expression might simply extract those desired digits:

```
^(?:https?://)(?:www\.)?imdb\.com/title/[a-z]+([0-9]+).*$
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ONejxB/1). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/ONejxB/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---